# How to show page numbers using right-to-left reading direction?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, culture

How can I change English numbers to Persian numbers in whole of my website without using JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your div,

```
<div dir="rtl" ... />
```